# Provide Additional Custom Metric to LightGBM for Early Stopping

Tags: python, lightgbm

I running a binary classification in LightGBM using the training API and want to stop on a custom metric while still tracking one or more builtin metrics.  It's not clear if this is possible, though.

Here we can disable the default `binary_logloss` metric and only track our custom metric:

```
import lightgbm as lgb

def my_eval_metric(...):
    ...

d_train = lgb.Dataset(...)
d_validate = lgb.Dataset(...)

params = {
    "objective": "binary",
    "metric": "custom",
}

evals_result = {}

model = lgb.train(
    params,
    d_train,
    valid_sets=[d_validate],
    feval=my_eval_metric,
    early_stopping_rounds=10,
    evals_result=evals_result,
)
```

If instead we let `metric` be default, we will also track `binary_logloss`, but we will stop on *both* metrics instead of just on our custom metric:

```
params = {
    "objective": "binary",
    # "metric": "custom",
}
```

We can set `first_metric_only`  in the `params`, but now we will stop *only* on `binary_logloss` as, apparently, it's the first metric:

```
params = {
    "objective": "binary",
    "first_metric_only": True,
}
```

Other things that probably work but seem like a pain:

1. It appears in the sklearn API that you can specify a list of evaluation metrics that intersperse callables for custom metrics and strings for builtin metrics; however, I would prefer not to switch to the sklearn API.
2. I could reimplement `binary_logloss` and pass it as a custom evaluation metric in a list with my other custom metric and use `first_metric_only`; however, it seems like I shouldn't have to do that.

Things that don't work:

1. `feval=[my_eval_metric, 'binary_logloss']` in the `lgb.train` call.  Complains that a string is not callable.
2. `metric: [my_eval_metric, 'binary_logloss']` in the `params` set.  Warns `Unknown parameter: my_eval_metric` and then errors when training starts with `ValueError: For early stopping, at least one dataset and eval metric is required for evaluation`.

Am I missing something obvious or is this a small hole in the LightGBM API?

This is on version 3.2.1.  On version 3.0.0, it seems like it's totally impossible to pass multiple custom evaluation metrics in the training API.  I'm not sure with the sklearn API there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are asking *"how do I perform early stopping based on a custom evaluation metric function?"*, that can be achieved by setting parameter `metric` to the string `"None"`. That will lead LightGBM to skip the default evaluation metric  based on the objective function (`binary_logloss`,  in your example)  and only perform early stopping on the custom metric function you've provided in `feval`.

The example below, using  `lightgbm==3.2.1` and `scikit-learn==0.24.1` on Python  3.8.8  reproduces this behavior.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

dtrain = lgb.Dataset(
    data=X_train,
    label=y_train
)

dvalid = lgb.Dataset(
    data=X_test,
    label=y_test,
    reference=dtrain
)

def _constant_metric(dy_true, dy_pred):
    """An eval metric that always returns the same value"""
    metric_name = 'constant_metric'
    value = 0.708
    is_higher_better = False
    return metric_name, value, is_higher_better

evals_result = {}

model = lgb.train(
    params={
        "objective": "binary",
        "metric": "None",
        "num_iterations": 100,
        "first_metric_only": True,
        "verbose": 0,
        "num_leaves": 8
    },
    train_set=dtrain,
    valid_sets=[dvalid],
    feval=_constant_metric,
    early_stopping_rounds=5,
    evals_result=evals_result,
)
```

You can see in the logs that the custom metric function I've provided is evaluated against the validation set, and training stops after `early_stopping_rounds` consecutive rounds without improvement.

```
[LightGBM] [Warning] Auto-choosing col-wise multi-threading, the overhead of testing was 0.000846 seconds.
You can set `force_col_wise=true` to remove the overhead.
[1] valid_0's constant_metric: 0.708
Training until validation scores don't improve for 5 rounds
[2] valid_0's constant_metric: 0.708
[3] valid_0's constant_metric: 0.708
[4] valid_0's constant_metric: 0.708
[5] valid_0's constant_metric: 0.708
[6] valid_0's constant_metric: 0.708
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[1] valid_0's constant_metric: 0.708
Evaluated only: constant_metric
```

If you are asking *"how do I provide a mix of built-in metrics and custom evaluation functions to `lgb.train()` and get all metrics evaluated, but only use the custom one for early stopping?"*...then yes, that is not supported as of `lightgbm` 3.2.1.